# PartialView or Model Inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Supposing I need to print the logged user on every page of my app.

Currently, I'm going with Model inheritance, using an ActionFilter that fills the user in my base Model, and displaying it : ( using a DisplayTemplate )

```
<% = Html.DisplayFor( x => x.CurrentUser ) %>
```

What about using a PartialView, called in the MasterPage using

```
<% = Html.Action("UserName", "BaseController") %>
```

Could this simplify things a bit in small to medium (20 models) applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think BaseViewModels are monsters that shouldn't be allowed to exist.  I can't think of a scenario where they don't become bloated with all sorts of superfluous logic that not all pages need.

`RenderAction()` has come a long way since MVC 1 and its finally getting full output caching support in MVC 3.  Because you gain a whole bunch of composibility with  `RenderAction` that you don't get with a ViewModelBase I prefer it.

Consider also that ViewModelBases also need ViewMasterModelBases to function resulting in even more tightly coupled logic that isn't easily swapped out.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a base ViewModel (I think thats what you were referring to) and dont mind assigning it every time or using a method attribute, see here...
[BaseViewModel stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115749/in-asp-net-mvc-what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-base-viewmodel-to-show-dynamic-con/4115801#4115801)

Personally I wouldnt mind have one controller method that returns a PartialView containing the user info. And then you just have the method call in your Site.Master wherever you want the user Markup displayed...

```
<% Html.RenderAction("UserInfo", "Home"); %>
```