# Can the shared layout view have a controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can the shared layout view have a controller?

I need to pass it Model information from a Controller?

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult Menu()
    {
        var ChargeTypes = db.ChargeTypes.ToList();
        return PartialView(ChargeTypes);
    }
```

And then its partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProposalMaker.Models.ChargeType>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.Name</li>
}
```

Then in the shared partial view

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Menu","ChargeType");}
```

Thanks for the tip SLaks!

Answer (score 5):

To pass information to the layout, you will need to use a base view model that is used by all your view models.  Your layout can then take this base model.

I have previously answered an SO question on this

[Pass data to layout that are common to all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13231752/1593273)

Which has a detailed example.

Comment: +1 for a nice approach and thanks for your suggestion. Although, I used my own approach below.