# How to send data from a controller to the dropdown list in _Layout.cshtml file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to send retrieved data from database in a controller to the '_Layout.cshtml' file. But not sure how can I pass the data from the controller to the _Layout.cshtml. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Why not you make a call from the page where you need those data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing data from Controller to View, there are three options below:

- Strongly typed data: viewmodel
- Weakly typed data

  - ViewData (ViewDataAttribute)
  - ViewBag

If you want to return different value from Controller to `_Layout.cshtml`, you could try `ViewData`.

Example:

1. Model

   ```
   public class UserVM
   {
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public string Value { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Layout.cshtml

   ```
   @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
   @{ 
       var users = ViewData["Users"] as List<UserVM>;
   }
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <body>

       <div class="container">
           <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
           <main role="main" class="pb-3">
               @foreach (var user in users)
               {
                   <div>@user.Value</div>
               }
               @RenderBody()
           </main>
       </div>    

       @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Controller  Action

   ```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
   {
       ViewData["Users"] = new List<UserVM> {
           new UserVM{ UserId = 1, Value = "Tom"},
           new UserVM{ UserId = 2, Value = "Jack"},
           new UserVM{ UserId = 3, Value = "Vicky"}
       };            
       return View();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ViewData or ViewBag to pass data to dropdown. 
The below link might help [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832124/can-the-shared-layout-view-have-a-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: But '_Layout.cshtml' view doesn't have any controller

Comment: @JatinKumar _Layout.cshtml does not need to have a `Controller` if you are using Templating, just pass the `ViewBag`, in all the `Controller` of all the pages that use the _Layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some service and inject in your layout.cshtml

Something like this

```
@inject MyService myService

@if(await myService.GetListOfData()) {
  // display data here
}
```

So in your serivce you can write like the nomarl service

```
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IRepository<ObjectDTO> _repo;
    public MyService(IRepository<ObjectDTO> repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<bool> GetListOfData()
    {
        var data = await _repo.Where(); // something
        return data;
    }
}
```