# What is @RenderSection in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the purpose of @RenderSection and how does it function? I understand what bundles do, but I have yet to figure out what this does and it's probably important.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Perhaps a small example on how to use it?

Answer (score 359, accepted):

If you have a _Layout.cshtml view like this

```
<html>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

then you can have an index.cshtml content view like this

```
@section scripts {
     <script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>
}
```

the *required* indicates whether or not the view using the layout page must have a scripts section

Comment: This doesn't answer the questions "what is the purpose?" and "how does it function?".

Comment: @Mathhew Agreed it does not answer the question.   The purpose is to allow the web page to load in the proper order. Assume your using a template for menus etc.  The loading page loads _layout.cshtml and then once all its elements have been loaded  _layout.cshtml calls the <body> section of the loading page using RenderBody to make sure its elements goes in the correct place.  Once all the elements are loaded the page specific scripts need loaded and RenderSection loads the scripts.   In a nut shell it is so things can be loaded in the proper order

Comment: Technically it "functions" by conditionally parsing the contents of a `section` block named scripts into a Token which contains an `HtmlString`, converts the result into a `TextWriter`, and writes the subsequent output to the `HttpResponse` as a handler in the ASP.NET Response Pipeline.

Answer (score 26):

Supposing that:

1. You have a `_Layout.cshtml` view like this.

```
<html>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
       
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/layout.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</html>
```

2. You have `Contacts.cshtml`.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/contacts.js"></script>

}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>    Contacts</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. You have `About.cshtml`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>    Contacts</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

On your layout page, if `required` is set to `false`: `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`, when the page renders and the user is on the about page, `contacts.js` won't render.

```
    <html>
        <body><div>About<div>             
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/layout.js"></script>
    </html>
```

If `required` is set to `true`: `@RenderSection("scripts", required: true)`, When page renders and user is on the About page, `contacts.js` *still* gets rendered.

```
<html>
    <body><div>About<div>             
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/layout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/contacts.js"></script>
</html>
```

**IN SHORT**, when set to **`true`**, whether you need it or not on other pages, it will get rendered anyhow.  If set to **`false`**, it will render only when the child page is rendered.

Comment: Is it just me or ... is this just wrong?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.rendersection?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Required parameter denotes that section is optional and It is your choice whether to use it or not. If you use true parameter then it is compulsory to use this section in child page otherwise you will get error.

Comment: But you did not mention the contact page?

Answer (score 8):

Suppose if I have GetAllEmployees.cshtml

```
<h2>GetAllEmployees</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
         // do something ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       // do something ...
    </tbody>
</table>

   //Added my custom scripts in the scripts sections

@section Scripts
    {
    <script src="~/js/customScripts.js"></script>
    }
```

And another view "GetEmployeeDetails.cshtml" with no scripts

```
<h2>GetEmployeeByDetails</h2>

@Model.PageTitle
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
       // do something ... 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       // do something ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my layout page "_layout.cshtml"

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
```

So, when I navigate to GetEmployeeDetails.cshtml. I get the error that there is no section scripts to be rendered in GetEmployeeDetails.cshtml. 
If I change the flag in `@RenderSection()` from `required : true` to ``required : false`. It means render the scripts defined in the @section scripts of the views if present.Else, do nothing.
And the refined approach would be in _layout.cshtml

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
    {
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here the defination of Rendersection from `MSDN`

> In layout pages, renders the content of a named section.[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.rendersection(v=vs.99))

In _layout.cs page put

```
@RenderSection("Bottom",false)
```

Here render the content of bootom section and specifies `false` boolean property to specify whether the section is required or not.

```
@section Bottom{
       This message form bottom.
}
```

That meaning if you want to bottom section in all pages, then you must use false as the second parameter at Rendersection method.