# MVC Hide navigation for some urls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a navigation on my `_Layout.cshtml`. How can i hide it for some views/urls? Do not want to use javascript for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a different Layout file based on your _Layout.chtml
- Remove the URLS you don't want.
- Update your views to use this layout.

Alternatively you can use a model for your layout page but from my experience it isn't worth the hassle.

Update - Example Using A Model in Layout

You essentially use a base model which is used for your layout and your view models inherit from it. [Here's a link to another SO question with example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages).

Comment: A model for the layout page? Sounds interesting as well. Any example. I know how i create a model for the views.