# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type... but this dictionary requires a model item of type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got an `MVC` project with a `Layout` that has `strongly typed` model named "`Dashboard`".

```
@model Dashboard_v2.Models.Dashboard
```

This Layout has a `RenderBody()` method that renders the rest of the pages.

then, on my main page, I have a View that is strongly typed with the Model `NewPatient`.

on the controller I have bunch of code, and eventually I pass a `NewPatient` Model to it.

When I try to run this code, I've got an error called :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Dashboard_v2.Models.NewPatient', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Dashboard_v2.Models.Dashboard'.
```

why does it expects a Dashboard Model, if my page has strongly typed NewPatient Model?

Comment: Why do you need a `Model` on a layout `View` anyway?

Comment: Remove the model definition from the layout. The model needs to be defined in the view (you are telling every view that its model must be `Dashboard`)

Comment: Optionally (i.e. _it's a must_), read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages).

Comment: If your wanting to render some details relating to `Dashboard` in all views, then in the layout use `@Html.Action()` to call a child action method that returns a partial view based on an instance `Dashboard`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to define a Viewmodel with generic parameter `MainViewModel<T>`and instance it with appreciated T for the views. Then you can use the `MainVewModel` properties in Layout and use properties of T in your views.