# Nested layout pages in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. I wanted to create nested layout pages for my view. For example, the hierarchy is as follows:

```
_Layout.cshtml > Template1.cshtml > FinalPage.cshtml
```

But what I am confused about is how to load data on the page: e.g., `Template1.cshtml` when I am loading the model and the controller calls `FinalPage.cshtml`.

Will it load by default without any changes?

Comment: For loading data there are a bunch of approaches. Describe a little more about your scenario.

Comment: I think the idea is pretty clear... interesting idea!

Comment: I would say: public ActionResult FinalPage()
        {
            return View("FinalPage");
        }

Comment: hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages helps. As a side, u could also look at partial pages which are reusbale components