# The model passed into dictionary is type 'TestApp.Models.Registration.RegistrationVm' but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.String

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the `Registration` controller:

```
public class RegistrationController : Controller
{
    private RegistrationVmBuilder _registrationVmBuilder = new RegistrationVmBuilder();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_registrationVmBuilder.BuildRegistrationVm());
    }

}
```

and the `RegistrationBuilder` class:

```
public class RegistrationVmBuilder
{
    public RegistrationVm BuildRegistrationVm()
    {
        RegistrationVm registrationVm = new RegistrationVm
        {
            Courses = GetSerializedCourseVms(),
            Instructors = GetSerializedInstructors()
        };
        return registrationVm;
    }
}
```

`RegistrationVm` class:

```
public class RegistrationVm
{
    public string Courses { get; set; }
    public string Instructors { get; set; }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
@model string
<html ng-app="registrationModule">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/registration-module.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("JavascriptInHead")
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-state.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>College Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

And in index view:

`@model TestApp.Models.Registration.RegistrationVm`

The problem is when i run the app I got this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'TestApp.Models.Registration.RegistrationVm', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

Comment: What line of your code gets this error?

Comment: @alisabzevari after I run the application in registration url.

Comment: What do you mean by registration url?

Comment: For example `http://localhost:30460/registration`

Comment: You have to trace your application from the start of you controller action to find where the error occurs.

Comment: What is the model of the `~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`? Are you sure _only_ `RegistrationsController.Index()` is being hit?

Comment: @CodeCaster is just general Layout to load in every page.

Comment: I didn't ask that. Does your layout have a `@model string` in it? Please show all relevant views.

Comment: Yeah remove the `@model string` from your `_Layout.cshtml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [shared _Layout.cshtml](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) has a model declared (`@model string`), which is inherited by any view that uses it. So essentially your Index view's model (`@model TestApp.Models.Registration.RegistrationVm`) is ignored.

I don't know why you have `@model string` in your _Layout view (the model doesn't seem to be used in there), but if you want to use inheritance see [Pass data to layout that are common to all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages).

Simply remove the model declaration from the shared layout.