# Share a model between view components in dotnet core

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a layout that has several view components, all of them are using the same viewmodel and the controller

so how can I do to share the same viewmodel instance between all of them?

this is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Metadata", Share-Model)
</head>
<body>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Header", Share-Model)
    <article id="main-content-article">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("Cover", Share-Model)
    </article>
    <section id="rest-fold-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <footer id="main-footer">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("Footer")
        </footer>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got it almost:

```
// inside View Component
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(SharedModel sharedmodel) { ... }
```

Inside *.cshtml:

```
@model MyApp.Models.SharedModel
...
    <article id="main-content-article">
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Cover", new { sharedmodel = model } )
</article>
```

Please note that the property in the anonymous class has the same name as the parameter in the `InvokeAsync` method. It's all clearly documented in the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/view-components.html#invoking-a-view-component) though.

Comment: I'm using these components in a layout, do you thinks is approach is still valid for dotnet core? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages/13231752#13231752