# Using two models in one view asp.net mvc - System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using model in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<DluzynaSzkola.Models.Aktualnosci>
```

and using the model for iteration to post data from Aktualnosci database:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dzien)</div>
}
```

Whenk moving to site, where layout page is used, and there is definded another model:

```
@model DluzynaSzkola.Models.User
```

it is throwing me System.NullReferenceException with error source exception:

> Wiersz 112: @foreach (var item in Model)

Why I can not use twice `@model` in one page? and how can I deal with that?

Comment: `Whenk moving to site` What does this sentence mean?

Comment: [Check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4764011/2224701)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages

Comment: A layout should not have a model (unless its a base view model). It means that every view that uses that layout must use the same model