# How to pass an array from controller to _layout.cshtml

Tags: javascript, arrays, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to pass an array to my _layout page (which does not have an @model).
The array must come from an controller method such as:

```
public IActionResult AssignLoan()
    {

        EntityDetails entity = new EntityDetails();
        entity.Name = (from o in _context.EntityDetails
                       select o.Name).ToString();



        entity.Name.ToArray();
        ViewData["populatedropdown"] = entity;

        return View();
    }
```

and the array must be passed to this section of the _layout view and must be set equal to var countries.

```
  var countries = ["Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa"];
```

Comment: `.ToString()` on your query makes no sense (do you mean `.ToList()`?) And `entity.Name.ToArray();` makes no sense since you do not assign the result to anything.

Comment: And what is the purpose of this? What are you wanting to do with the array?

Comment: I am quite new to this, so the query result must be set to an array and that array must be passed to my view with no @model

Comment: I want to pass the array to my _layout view to that is populates a searchable dropdownlist

Comment: Then you are going about it all wrong. In the layout, you use `@Url.Action(...)` to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` controller method that returns a partial view (and that partial view will be strongly bound to a model, and use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty, Model.SomeSelectList)`

Comment: check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225315/pass-data-to-layout-that-are-common-to-all-pages/32725208#answer-31034711

Comment: I understand thank you @StephenMuecke

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is ASP.NET Core. There's no such thing as child actions. The closest thing is a view component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a view component. Add a folder called `ViewComponents` to your project and add the following class. Obviously, change `Foo` to a name that actually describes what this does.

```
public class FooViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var list = // get your list
        return View(list);
    }
}
```

Then, add a view at `Views\Shared\Components\Foo\Default.cshtml`. Inside, put the HTML that renders you drop down list.

Finally, in your layout:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Foo")
```

Where `"Foo"` is the name of your view component minus the `ViewComponent` part. View components are injectable, so if you need access to your context or something, you simply add a constructor that receives that as a param and assign it to an ivar, just as you would with a controller. Also, `InvokeAsync` can be passed parameters if you need them. For example:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string foo)
```

And then:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Foo", new { foo = "bar" })
```

More information can be found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.